# open3d and realsense camera L515 connection

Tags: python, 3d-reconstruction, open3d, realsense

I am trying to create a online reconstruction pipeline mode using open3d, the camera i am using is intel realsense L515. i have made the program that works on dataset, but when it comes to online reconstruction:
i am having confusion about:

1. how to connect camera and python ?
2. convert input from camera to .ply format

It would be great if you can provide answer to the question or provide whole code for onlinr reconstruction  to reffer.

I tried making the code work on data set but camera connectivity is a big problem for me. in all can you give me code that takes input and save point cloud in.ply format

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer to your question but I am currently working on a similar project and I found [an example](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/1437#issuecomment-576583709) that access Azure Kinect and convert a single rgbd frame to a point cloud pcd that can be saved to a .ply file using the function o3d.io.write_point_cloud(output_path, pcd). I think you can replace o3d.io.AzureKinectSensor with o3d.t.io.RealSenseSensor because RealSense is also supported in the Open3D API http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.t.io.RealSenseSensor.html